# Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object, but the Object is Already Created

Tags: c#, object, reference, instance

Hi guys I'm making a game about ninjas in C# and this line is giving me the runtime error message about reference not being set to an instance of an Object
here is the line that gives the error:

```
string status = "Score: " + knife.KnivesLeft.ToString();
```

Here is the full game code below:

```
using SnapsLibrary;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Knifer
{
    interface IGameSprite
    {
        void Reset();
        void Update();
    }
    public abstract class MovingSprite : IGameSprite
    {
        public ImageSprite spriteValue;
        public double xSpeedValue, ySpeedValue;

        public MovingSprite(ImageSprite sprite, double xSpeed, double ySpeed)
        {
            spriteValue = sprite;
            xSpeedValue = xSpeed;
            ySpeedValue = ySpeed;
        }
        public virtual void Update()
        {
            spriteValue.X = spriteValue.X + xSpeedValue;
            spriteValue.Y = spriteValue.Y + ySpeedValue;
        }
        public virtual void Reset()
        {

        }
    }
    public class KnifeSprite : MovingSprite
    {
        public bool IsFlying = false;
        public NinjaSprite ninjaValue;
        public KnifeSprite knifeValue;
        public KniferGame gameValue;
        public int KnivesLeft;

        public KnifeSprite(KniferGame game, ImageSprite sprite,NinjaSprite Petya, double xSpeed, double ySpeed) : base(sprite: sprite, xSpeed: xSpeed, ySpeed: ySpeed)

        {
            gameValue = game;
            ninjaValue = Petya;
            spriteValue = sprite;
            xSpeedValue = xSpeed;
            ySpeedValue = ySpeed;
            spriteValue.CenterX = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 2;
            spriteValue.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;
        }
        public override void Update()
        {
            if (SnapsEngine.GetFireGamepad())
                IsFlying = true;
            if (!IsFlying)
                return;
            base.Update();
            if(spriteValue.IntersectsWith(ninjaValue.spriteValue))
            {
                ninjaValue.Kill();
            }
            if (spriteValue.Bottom < 0)
            {
                IsFlying = false;
                KnivesLeft = KnivesLeft - 1;
                if (KnivesLeft == 0)
                {
                    gameValue.EndCurrentGame();
                }
                spriteValue.CenterX = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 2;
                spriteValue.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;
            }
        }
        public override void Reset()
        {
            spriteValue.CenterX = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 2;
            spriteValue.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;
            KnivesLeft = 3;
        }
        public void KnifeCountdown()
        {
            KnivesLeft = KnivesLeft - 1;
            if (KnivesLeft==0)
            {
                gameValue.EndCurrentGame();
            }
        }

    }
    public class NinjaSprite:IGameSprite
    {
        public ImageSprite spriteValue;
        public int NinjasRemaining; 
        public int countToFly;
        public int NinjaSpeed;
        public double originalX, originalY;
        public int countdown;
        public int countToFlyOriginal;

        public NinjaSprite(ImageSprite sprite,int countdown,int speed,int remaining)
        {
            NinjasRemaining = remaining;
            NinjaSpeed = speed;
            countToFly = countdown;
            spriteValue = sprite;
            spriteValue.Right = 40;
            spriteValue.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight/3;
            originalX = spriteValue.Right;
            originalY = sprite.Bottom;
            countToFlyOriginal = countToFly;
        }
                public void Reset()
        {
            spriteValue.Right = originalX;
            spriteValue.Bottom = originalY;
            countToFly = countToFlyOriginal;
            spriteValue.Show();
        }
        public void Kill()
        {
            spriteValue.Hide();
            NinjasRemaining = NinjasRemaining - 1;
            if (NinjasRemaining == 0)
                SnapsEngine.PlayGameSoundEffect("ding");
            Reset();
            Update();
        }
        public void Update()
        {
            countToFly = countToFly - 1;
            if (countToFly<=0)
            {
                spriteValue.X = spriteValue.X + NinjaSpeed;               
            }
            if (spriteValue.X >SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth)
                Reset();
        }
    }
    public class KniferGame
    {
        List<IGameSprite> sprites = new List<IGameSprite>();
        GameStates state;
        ImageSprite titleScreen;
        KnifeSprite knife;
        ImageSprite IntermissionScreen;
        ImageSprite gameOverScreen;
        TextBlockSprite messageBack,message;
        int gameScore;
        enum GameStates
        {
            TitleScreen,
            GameActive,
            Intermission,
            GameOver
        }
        public void ShowTitleScreen()
        {
            //gameOverScreen.Hide();
            titleScreen.Show();
            state = GameStates.TitleScreen;
        }

        void ResetGame()
        {
            gameScore = 0;
            foreach (IGameSprite sprite in sprites)
                sprite.Reset();
        }

        void SetupGame()
        {
            SnapsEngine.StartGameEngine(fullScreen: false, framesPerSecond: 60);
            ImageSprite backgroundImage = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/wood tile background1000x1000.png");
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(backgroundImage);
            backgroundImage.ScaleSpriteWidth(SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth);

            ImageSprite NinjaImage = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/ninja copy.png");
            NinjaImage.ScaleSpriteWidth(SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 10);
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(NinjaImage);
            NinjaSprite ninja1 = new NinjaSprite(NinjaImage,120,10,3);
            sprites.Add(ninja1);

            ImageSprite KnifeImage = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/knife1.png");
            KnifeImage.ScaleSpriteWidth(SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 20);
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(KnifeImage);
            KnifeSprite knife = new KnifeSprite(game:this,sprite:KnifeImage, Petya:ninja1, xSpeed:0, ySpeed:-20);
            sprites.Add(knife);

            titleScreen = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/SpaceRocketsInSpaceTitleScreen.png");
            titleScreen.Hide();
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(titleScreen);
            titleScreen.Width = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth;
            titleScreen.Height = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;

            IntermissionScreen = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/wood tile background1000x1000.png");
            IntermissionScreen.Hide();
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(IntermissionScreen);
            IntermissionScreen.Width = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth;
            IntermissionScreen.Height = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;

            gameOverScreen = new ImageSprite(imageURL: "ms-appx:///Images/SpaceRocketsInSpaceGameOverScreen.png");
            gameOverScreen.Hide();
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(gameOverScreen);
            gameOverScreen.Width = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth;
            gameOverScreen.Height = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight;

            messageBack = new TextBlockSprite(text: "", fontSize: 60,
                fontFamily: "Impact", color: SnapsColor.Black);
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(messageBack);

            message = new TextBlockSprite(text: "", fontSize: 60,
                fontFamily: "Impact", color: SnapsColor.Red);
            SnapsEngine.AddSpriteToGame(message);

        }

        public void EndCurrentGame()
        {
            titleScreen.Hide();
            gameOverScreen.Show();
            state = GameStates.GameOver;
            gameOverTimer = 0;
        }

        public void StartNewGame()
        {
            ResetGame();
          //gameOverScreen.Hide();
            titleScreen.Hide();
            state = GameStates.GameActive;
        }
        int intermissionTimer;
        public void UpdateIntermission()
        {
            titleScreen.Hide();
            IntermissionScreen.Show();
            state = GameStates.Intermission;
            gameOverTimer = 0;
            intermissionTimer = intermissionTimer + 1;
            if (intermissionTimer > 100)
            {
                IntermissionScreen.Hide();
                StartNewGame();
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTitle()
        {
            if (SnapsEngine.GetFireGamepad())
            {
                UpdateIntermission();
                //StartNewGame();
            }
        }
        int gameOverTimer=0;
        public void UpdateGameOver()
        {
            gameOverTimer = gameOverTimer + 1;
            if (gameOverTimer > 300)
            {
                ShowTitleScreen();
            }
        }

        public void UpdateGame()
        {
            foreach (IGameSprite sprite in sprites)
                sprite.Update();

            string status = "Score: " + knife.KnivesLeft.ToString();
            message.Text = status;
            messageBack.Text = status;

            messageBack.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight - 74;
            messageBack.CenterX = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 6;

            message.Bottom = SnapsEngine.GameViewportHeight - 70;
            message.CenterX = SnapsEngine.GameViewportWidth / 6 + 4;
        }
        public void PlayGame()
        {
            SetupGame();

            ResetGame();

            ShowTitleScreen();


            while (true)
            {
                    switch (state)
                     {
                        case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                            UpdateTitle();
                            break;
                        case GameStates.Intermission:
                            UpdateIntermission();
                            break;
                        case GameStates.GameActive:
                            UpdateGame();
                            break;
                        case GameStates.GameOver:
                            UpdateGameOver();
                            break;
                }
                SnapsEngine.DrawGamePage();
            }
        }
    }
    public void StartProgram()
    {
        KniferGame game = new KniferGame();
        game.PlayGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is that error on?

Comment: the line is 270 string status = "Score: " + knife.KnivesLeft.ToString();

Comment: my man, there are no line numbers on stack, so how will i know what 270 is?

Comment: @zaitsman I guess search is the only way to do that :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line in `SetupGame()`.

```
KnifeSprite knife = new KnifeSprite(game:this,sprite:KnifeImage, Petya:ninja1, xSpeed:0, ySpeed:-20);
```

You are declaring a *new* local variable called `knife`, and never populating the field called `knife`. So it stays null forever.

Change it to:

```
this.knife = new KnifeSprite(game:this,sprite:KnifeImage, Petya:ninja1, xSpeed:0, ySpeed:-20);
```

Comment: Please, add the line number. Being serious, well done with that scope issue.

Comment: It's in `SetupGame()` on the 14th line (including the declaration). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks John, your solution fixed the problem. Which class contains knife field, that I wasn't populating? I was using another code as template, but it didn't have this. In front of the object name.

Comment: Whenever you see `this.`+ a field name, it means you are accessing a field within the same class that contains the code you see it in. In this case it's `KniferGame`.

Comment: Hi John, now I'm trying to make level 2 and the error returned again with a vengeance, I poasted the new thread, can you take a look pls.